# QGIS Oracle Schema Connection

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms

In QGIS is there any way I can connect to and list tables for only one specific schema (among many schemas and not the same schema as my username) in oracle?  In the "Create New Oracle connection" box, can I use these two fields "Options" and "Workspace" to achieve this?[image]